# C++ - Can type_info::name determine if a type is a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, typeid, typeinfo

I need to categorise a template type in c++. One thing which I need to determine is whether a given type is a pointer - I was wondering if `std::type_info::name()` would be a suitable way to determine something like that.

This:

```
std::cout << typeid(T).name();
```

Appears to work - it appears a `P` is added before the object class-type, but is this a reliable (and correct) way to implement such a system?

Comment: `std::is_pointer`?  (Although it has some limitations)

Comment: If you want to query information of the type, use the [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library

Comment: No, it's almost never correct to use `type_info`. It's more of a compiler debugging feature than something you should use in production code. It's non-portable and implementation defined, not guaranteed to stay the same between versions. You are already using templates, use proper mechanisms from `<type_traits>`